# What's the most elegant workaround for the lack of DefaultFileName in SaveFileDialog in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, savefiledialog

The SaveFileDialog in Silverlight lacks a DefaultFileName property, resulting in the user having to enter the file name manually with every file download from a Silverlight application.

This is very annoying and there's a lot of criticism about this, see [the Silverlight forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/117702.aspx).

My question is: what is the most elegant way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare the download and let aspx handle the download for you:

http://strugglesofacoder.blogspot.com/2011/03/alternative-to-saving-file-in.html

Comment: Thanks, ultimately, this is basically how we did it. Thanks for the comprehensive blog post.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add one suggestion as an anwser myself, which I picked up from the mentioned forum:

Copy the file name to the clipboard so users only have to press Ctrl-V in the dialog.