# SL4 saveFileDialog.DefaultFileName work around

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dialog, savefiledialog

I found the code below in [this post](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/117702.aspx/6/10#) but I can't get it to work...

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.GetType().GetMethod("set_DefaultFileName").Invoke(dialog, new object[] { "FileName.ext" });
```

Any ideas...

I know this is horrible and unsafe but I prefer the risk over subjecting my user to such a crappy UX.  And SL 5 is not an option in the near term.

There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5457187/456490) but I need something a little quicker for my demo/proof of concept to show to my customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work cause there is no method called set_DefaultFileName (or no property called DefaultFileName)- have a look yourself with a tool like Reflector/dotPeek.

That technique will work in Silverlight 5, but there is no need, as you can simply do the following:

saveFileDialog.DefaultFileName = "FileName.ext";

I suspect the original poster was doing that on a Silverlight 5 Beta, and didn't notice the property?

You best bet is taking the approach described in the Stackoverflow answer that you link to.